# Can you teleport someone else out of a grapple?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

An interesting idea struck me during a combat in a recent game; we were being attacked by a [Chuul](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/chuul.htm) and our hapless gnome had been caught and grappled by the beast.

A crazy idea came to my mind, that my Wizard could fly over to them  and then grab hold of their head/arm/anything and then use the Conjuration ability [Dimensional Steps](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/conjuration) to rescue them from the grip of the beast.

Is there any reason why as long as the Wizard could get a grip on the gnome this wouldn't save them from the clawy grip of the Chuul? 
Or indeed a spell like Dimension Door? (Provided the Wizard survives the impending attack of opportunity!)

Comment: Note that if the Chuul is grappling the Gnome then he can't get an AoO on the Wizard next to the grapple because he has no threatened space while grappling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes.

There is nothing in the rules that says that a grappled creature cannot teleport themselves to escape a grapple. They simply need to pass a concentration check to cast a spell/use their spell like ability while grappled.

I can see no reason why this would not extend to someone else casting a teleport style spell for them.

Comment: There is a possible complication though: both **Dimension Door** and **Teleportation** states: *[...] You may also bring [...] additional willing creatures [...] All creatures to be transported must be in contact with one another, and at least one of those creatures must be in contact with you.* - since the Chull is willing and holding the gnome - won't you end up bringing him along with you?

Comment: @G0BLiN No. the spellcaster gets to choose who the additional targets are for the teleport. Either way, are you sure the chuul would be willing to let an enemies spell take affect, especially if you know it is a spell taking you to who knows where?

Comment: Yeah, you are right there on both points - the wizard gets to [specify the targets](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell), and the Chull is likely to have no idea what spell the wizard is casting, so it makes little sense he'll be "willing" (unless you try to pull this stunt more than once on the same Chull). As a final note - in D&D-3.5, attempting to touch a grappled creature had 25% hitting the **other** grappler - so you could have ended up taking *just the Chull* with you... I can't find a similar notion in PF though.

Comment: I suppose a good follow up question is "How can I touch someone being grappled to cast a spell on them."

Comment: I found another snag: Dimension Door is not *range: touch*, which means you do not get to touch someone as part of the casting, nor can you hold the charge until you touch someone. You cast it, you teleport. In this case, the "touching" might have to be done by the grappled character (which likely calls for a grapple check) instead of the caster, maybe using a readied action ("I try reach for the wizard just as he casts his spell"). This has the benefit of requiring a roll, and it uses the grappled character's round as well (which seems only fair).